# What is the probability that only 3 people will receive at least 1 ball?

Tags: probability

> 10 identical balls are being distributed to 5 people. All the outcomes are equally likely outcomes. What is the probability that exactly 3 people will receive at least 1 ball?

At first I thought that I should refer to this question as if the balls were different, then the calculation would have been something like this:

[image]

But the answer isn't correct. Where were I wrong?

Comment: Would you consider your event to include outcomes where two people get all the balls, or must the number of people who get any balls be _exactly_ $3$?

Comment: You seem not to be considering the "only" part.

Comment: Yeah, the word "only" in this cases is a little ambiguous. I'd guess the question means "exactly three" rather than "at most three," but I'm not sure.

Comment: "The distribution probability is equal" is very imprecise. It is not clear what probability model is being used. Also, does only $3$ people mean exactly $3$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, I mean exactly 3 people. and by "The distribution probability is equal" i mean that every ball has the same probability to be disturbed to any of the people.

Comment: I would use your model, with $5^{10}$ equally likely outcomes. That gives $\binom{5}{2}(3/5)^{10}$. But they may, unreasonably, intend one to use a model in which all the "Stars and Bars" possibilities are equally likely.

Comment: With the changed wording, the possibility they mean Stars and Bars outcomes has increased. With that interpretation there are $\binom{14}{4}$ equally likely outcomes, and $\binom{5}{2}\binom{9}{2}$ "favourables." If you know what they assert the answer to be, you can check whether that answer is consistent with the revised interpretation.

Comment: Wait, if you know the right answer, and that $559800$ is wrong, why did you select my answer? What is the right answer? that might help us determine the correct intent of the question.

Comment: And yes, the phrase "all the outcomes are equally likely" is somewhat opaque. It depends on what is meant by two outcomes being the same, which depends on both whether the balls are distinguishable and whether the players are distinguishable. (Usually, when dealing with people, we consider them distinguishable, whereas if they were just urns, we would not necessarily.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I thought that maybe the book I'm reading from is wrong. That's why I've accepted your previous answer. But actually after the correction you've made, it turns our the book was correct all along. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the meaning of the term "outcome" here. Usually, just based on human intuition, we assume that humans are distinguishable, since Amy getting 3 balls and Jim getting none feels very different that the reverse.

But if the balls are indistinguishable, then the *outcome* is a sequence if natural numbers $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$ such that $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=10$. There are $\binom{14}{4}$ such sequences, and if they are the outcome, then being equally likely is *different* than distributing the balls randomly one at a time.

For example, if the outcomes are equally likely, it is just as likely that player  one gets all ten balls as every player gets exactly two balls.

Then, given three players, we want three positive numbers adding up to $10$. That is the same as three non-negative numbers adding up to $7$, which is $\binom{9}{2}=36$.

So the total probability with that reading is $$\frac{\binom{5}{3}\binom{9}{2}}{\binom{14}{4}}=\frac{360}{1001}$$

Your inclusion/exclusion reading is right if the balls are distributed independently, or are distinguishable.

Comment: I got a slightly different result, can you please have a look?

Comment: Your approach was basically working, as I mentioned, you just had to subtract three times the second term, and take care of how often you counted and excluded the cases where only one person got the ball. (You counted each $\binom{4}{2}=6$ times in the first term, then subtracted them $3\binom{4}{1}$ times in the second term, so to have to add the five back six times, to get $+\binom{5}{1}\left(3\binom{4}{2}-\binom{4}{1}\right)=+30$, which finally agrees with my answer. @barakmanos

Comment: I would have fixed and kept your answer, since it is always nice to see two different approaches yield the same value. @barakmanos